# Is it possible to remove decals from the Orbea Gain frame?

Tags: frames, decals

I’m looking into buying the Orbea Gain electric bike. But I really dislike the big Orbea logo on the frame.

Do you think it’s possible to remove this without ruining the paint somehow? The decal is raised, so it’s not painted, but don’t know if it’s coated on top.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you choose the M series you can personalize the bike. While the logo will still be there, you can request it to be black-on-black or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

That is very unlikely. The decals will be protected by some clear layers of paint or lacquer or polish or whatever is the right term. Rather, you should be able to re-paint the frame.

Comment: Clear coat is the technical term. So, if these were vinyl decals under the clear coat, then clearly you can use some fine grit sandpaper to get the clearcoat off and then take out the decals. I am not sure if you can re-coat the frame seamlessly. The process could leave the frame looking marred.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Yes, that is what I am afraid of. Definitely, after a good recoating the paint under those past decals will probably look nicer than around and the whole are will look slightly differently and less worn. So for perfect look one would want to repaint the whole tube.

Answer (score 3):

Consider wrapping the downtube with opaque black paint protection film. Modifying the paint is going to void your warranty, which I'm sure you'd like to keep. If you ever sell the bike, the future owner may want to have the brand logo on there still, so a reversible change would be my recommendation.